# Error when setting up klarna payments in flutter_stripe

Tags: flutter, flutter-stripe

I am using the `flutter_stripe` library to setup payments in my app but am seeing an error that does not seem to be covered in their documentation.

This is my code:

```
       final paymentIntent = await Stripe.instance.confirmPayment(
            paymentIntentClientSecret: store.state.basket.intentSecret!,
            data: PaymentMethodParams.klarna(
              paymentMethodData: PaymentMethodData(
                  billingDetails: billingDetails,
                  shippingDetails: shippingDetails),
            ),
            options: const PaymentMethodOptions(),
          );
```

Following the example on this page:

https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/lib/screens/regional_payment_methods/klarna_screen.dart

I get the following error:

```
StripeException(error: LocalizedErrorMessage(code: FailureCode.Failed, localizedMessage: There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds, message: You must provide a `return_url` when confirming a PaymentIntent with the payment method type klarna., stripeErrorCode: , declineCode: null, type: invalid_request_error))
```

As far as i can tell there is no way to provide a `return_url` parameter to the `confirmPayment` method, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a `Stripe.urlScheme = 'stripe-app';` that needs to be set globally for pay later methods in the stripe library.